# Subquery in `where` with comparison operator

Tags: hive, partitioning, hiveql

Let's say I have a large table partitioned by `dt` field. I want to query this table for data after specific date. E.g.

```
select * from mytab where dt >= 20140701;
```

The tricky part is that **date** is not a constant, but **comes from a subquery**. So basically I want something like this:

```
select * from mytab where dt >= (select min(dt) from activedates);
```

Hive can't do it, however, giving me `ParseException` on subquery (from docs I'm guessing it's just not supported yet).

So how do I restrict my query based on dynamic subquery?

Note, that performance is key point here. So the faster, the better, even if it looks uglier.

Also note, that we haven't switched to Hive 0.13 yet, so solutions without `in` query are preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hive decides on the partition pruning when building the execution plan and thus has to have the value of the `max(dt)` prior to execution.

Currently the only way to accomplish something like this is breaking the query into two parts, when the first will be `select min(dt) from activedates`, its results will be put into a variable.
2nd query will be : `select * from mytab where dt >=${hiveconf:var}`.

Now this is a bit tricky.
You could either execute the 1st query into OS variable like so :

```
a=`hive -S -e "select min(dt) from activedates"`
```

And then run the 2nnd query like so :

```
hive -hiveconf var=$a -e "select * from mytab where dt >=${hiveconf:var}"
```

or event just :

```
hive -e "select * from mytab where dt >=$a"
```

Or, if you are using some other scripting language you can replace the variable in the code.